# Regex match pattern between tags plug a specific string

Tags: regex

I have this content

```
<something>; rel="previous", <something>; rel="next"
```

I want to match 
`<something>; rel="next"`

This matches the entire line strangely

```
(<.+?>); rel="next"
```

Can anyone lend me a hand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(<[^>]+>); rel="next"` to avoid gobbling the whole line.